# Stop accordion collapsing on checking checkbox in react

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, accordion, react-bootstrap, stoppropagation

Using react-bootstrap accordion. The 1st accordion remains open all the time. However when i click checkbox inside 2nd accordion it collapses the accordion. I've tried putting an onClick on the checkboxes and then e.stopPropagation(). This does not work.
The accordion is a child of main page & checkboxes children of accordion.
The checkboxes on change is passed from main to accordion as property.
This is onchange function for checkboxes on main page.

```
const handleOnChange = (position) => {
// position used to save details to state in main page
}
```

This is the accordion component

```
const AccordionComp = ({ list, handleOnChange, checkedState }) => {
  return (
    <Accordion defaultActiveKey={["0"]} alwaysOpen flush>
      <Accordion.Item eventKey="0">
        <Accordion.Header>Popular</Accordion.Header>
        <Accordion.Body>
          <Row className="justify-content-md-center pt-2" key={1}>
            <Col className="optionCheckbox mx-10">
              {list.slice(0, 11).map((eq, idx) => (
                <Form.Group key={idx}>
                  <Form.Check
                    type="checkbox"
                    name={eq.name}
                    id={`options-${eq._id}`}
                    label={eq.name}
                    checked={checkedState[idx]}
                    onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e, idx)}
                  />
                </Form.Group>
              ))}
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Accordion.Body>
      </Accordion.Item>
      <Accordion.Item eventKey="1">
        <Accordion.Header>Other</Accordion.Header>
        <Accordion.Body>
          <Row className="justify-content-md-center pt-2" key={1}>
            <Col className="optionCheckbox mx-10">
              {list.slice(12, 24).map((eq, idx) => {
                let newIndex = 12 + idx;
                return (
                  <Form.Group key={newIndex}>
                    <Form.Check
                      type="checkbox"
                      name={eq.name}
                      id={`options-${eq._id}`}
                      label={eq.name}
                      checked={checkedState[newIndex]}
                      onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
                      onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e, newIndex)}
                    />
                  </Form.Group>
                );
              })}
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Accordion.Body>
      </Accordion.Item>
    </Accordion>
  );
};
```

Any help to stop 2nd accordion collapsing until directly requested would be very gratefully received. Thank you

Comment: you have to use the disabled attribute of the Accordion.Item component. By conditionally setting the disabled attribute to true based on whether the checkbox is clicked or not, you can prevent the accordion from collapsing. I can help you if you'll share codesandbox of the same.

Answer (score 0):

please check the version of react-bootstrap. using 2.8.0 working fine for me.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-accordion-forked-c4kzd3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you, this didn't change anything. However i changed by page layout and removed the components. Then it worked correctly